# Add more than one data in a field in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table named 'users' . In 'users' table, contains a field named 'chapter_id' . 
Another table named 'chapters' contains all the name of the chapters of a particular subject with respect to their id. I want to add more than one 'id' from 'chapters' to 'chapter_id' in users. 
I am able to add one 'chapter_id' in 'users' from 'chapters'.
Here is my users table :

```
-------------------------
id | name | chapter_id  |
-------------------------
1  | ABC  |    8        |
-------------------------
```

---

Here is my 'chaprers' table:

```
-------------------------
id | name |   subject   |
-------------------------
1  | XYZ  |   PQR       |
-------------------------
```

---

The query that I used to select the name from 'chapters' where 'id' = 'some id' in table 'users' is :

```
SELECT `name`, subject FROM chapters WHERE id = (SELECT chapter_id FROM users where id= 11)
```

And to insert the chapter_id, I wrote :

```
UPDATE `users` SET `chapter_id`= (SELECT id FROM chapters WHERE id = 5) WHERE id =11
```

Now I want to add more than one 'id' in 'chapter_id' ! What is the query to do that?

Comment: You are looking for a Many-to-Many association.

Comment: Can you add some more sample data and Expected Output.

Comment: umm. `chapter_id=select id from chapters where id=5`? What is the point of that? why not `chapter_id=5`?

Comment: You can't insert more than one `chapter_id` into a single value.

Comment: Don't confuse yourself and us, INSERT is used to insert a row in a table. UPDATE is used to update one (or several) already existing rows!

Comment: @jarlh, I have used UPDATE because I have the value defined as NULL! The field 'chapter_id' was introduced later .
What I want is, to make a page that enables user to follow one or more topics. When user follows that topic, he should get updated about anything happens new in that topic! How to store the id's of the topics more than one and the topic's id get stored in the database 'users'!

Comment: @Marc B, could be to insert NULL if no id = 5 exists? (Or to get an error if there are several rows with id = 5...)

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible. What you need is a join table, where each row contains a reference to a User and a Chapter. Then, you can have multiple rows per user, each refering to a chapter (and thus, multiple chapters per user.)

But more importantly: Read up on SQL. You will never be able to develop anything using SQL if you don't understand the basics.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the structure of your DB.

Now, you have a **1 to N relation**, where a single user can have only one chapter assigned, but every chapter can be assigned to multiple users.

You need the opposite, a **N to 1 relation**, where every chapter has an assigned user. To do this, you'll need to remove your current `chapter_id` column and add a `user_id` column in your chapter table.

If you want otherwise, like a **N to N relation** (a user can have multiple chapter assigned, and any chapter can have multiple users assigned), you'll need a new table in the middle.